# react native margin between keyboard and input

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, input

how can i put margin between input and keyboard? So that i can see the border Bottom. And how i can change the color of the blink element in input field?

**This is wrong**
[image: This is wrong]

**Keyboard hidden**

[image: Keyboard hidden]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's all in the react-native docs:

Keyboard issue: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html

Cursor Color changing: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#selectioncolor

Comment: You can use behavior padding.

Comment: or if you want something more controlled, hook into the keyboard listeners and adjust that element however you want when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: use  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" along with the KeyboardAvoidingView